# Cassandra - CQLSH - select * from table; Without the ---MORE---

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Small question regarding Cassandra and cqlsh please.

I have a table, not too big, 300+ rows.

Hence, I want to select all in one go, to see the data, 300 is nothing crazy.

Therefore, I run the basic `select * from mytable;`

Each time, it gives only 100 rows. Then, I see a "more"

`---MORE---`

How to skip this `---MORE---` and to return everything in one go please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `PAGING` command in `cqlsh` ([docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11.5/tools/cqlsh.html#paging)). To disable it, enter `PAGING OFF;`